# Create a dictionary in clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, key

I want to create a json representation of one known key and variable amount of unknown:

```
(defn test1 [var1 & var2]
  (print json/write-str :key1 var1 var2))

(defn -main [& args]
  (test1 "key1_val" {:key2 "val2" :key3 "val3"}))
```

It returns this:

```
  :key1 key1_val ({:key2 val2, :key3 val3})
```

I want it to be a single dictionary. I wonder, is what the method returned really what I'm looking for? I think not because the 2nd part is in the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(print json/write-str :key1 var1 var2)`

This prints the function value of `json/write-str`, followed by the value of each of the keys. In clojure if you want a function to run, you must apply it, this is usually done by wrapping it in parenthesis.

Next, `write-str` takes multiple args, but the only arg that is turned into json is the first, so you need to wrap your data in a data structure.

I'm not sure how you really want the data structured, but something like this is closer I think:

`(json/write-str {:key1 [var1 var2]})`

Also, as a minor note, the code did not return `:key1 key1_val ({:key2 val2, :key3 val3})`, it printed the string ":key1 key1_val ({:key2 val2, :key3 val3})", and returned `nil`, because println always returns `nil`.

Comment: my goal is to get "{key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3}. You solution returns "{:key1 [key1_val ({:key2 val2, :key3 val3})]}"

Comment: in my example "var2" here `[var1 & var2]` is of type dictionary and var1 is a string (the value for the key "key1_val"

Comment: in an args list of `[var1 & var2]` var2 is guaranteed to never be a dictionary. It will be a list. That's what `&` does.

Comment: so how can I turn it into a dictionary?

Comment: one way would be to use `[var1 var2]` as your argument list.